# InvalidRegistration when sending Firebase data messages with https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

1. I setup a REST client with POST --> https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
2. Content-Type : application/json
3. Authorization : key=`<server-key>`
4. JSON Body:

   { 
     "to": "testTopic",
     "data": {
       "key1" : "val1",
       "key2" : true
     }
   }

The repsonse in 200 OK but the response body has:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6098503498585,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results":[
        {
        "error": "InvalidRegistration"
        }
    ]
}
```

**So the onMessageReceived() is not triggered, neither app in foreground nor in background? Why do I get *InvalidRegistration* ? What am I missing?**

The server key at point 3 is from Firebase Project settings --> Cloud messaging --> Server key

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 4. your JSON requires a preceeding

> /topics/

for "to" thus:

```
{ "to": "/topics/testTopic",....}
```